# Is moving often going to look like job-hopping?

Tags: job-hopping

My partner and I are starting to settle into a lifestyle where we move where we live a lot. Because of circumstances both of us have to work close to where we live. Moving more than once every two years is the norm, not the exception, it seems.

With the above in mind, will we look like job-hoppers to interviewers when the reason for leaving a job has nothing to do with the job at all, and rather where and how we choose to live? Is there any structural way we could protect ourselves from these perceptions?

Comment: How is what you are doing not job-hopping? Unless you have some special circumstances (for example - if one of you is in the military and has to relocate for work and the other chooses to follow), you are choosing to leave a job after a short period of time. I suppose the only difference is that not everyone leaves the geographic area at the rate that you do. Is contract work or fully remote work a possibility?

Comment: No it's not gonna look **like** job-hopping, this is job-hopping.

Comment: Depends also on what "moving a lot" means, is it more in the range of every few months, every year, every two years, every couple of years? And what's the industry? In some, regular job changes are the norm in some not. And for some industries there might be ways to avoid most negative effects, e.g. by working as a freelancer on a project basis.

Comment: What do you do for a living?  Also, please add a country tag.

Comment: If you have been moving every 2 years, and you're going to keep moving every 2 years, them having a perception that you'll only stay for 2 years seems about right. Being labelled a job hopper doesn't have all that much to do with the reason why you move, the bottom line is how long you'll stay.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes. Yes, you will.**

Employers care why you're moving, sure. If you had been fired that would be bad.

However, spending tens of thousands of dollars to bring someone on board, only to replace him a year later is also severely unpleasant, no matter the cause.

For them, this will represent money wasted. You could, at the end of this transition period, reassure prospective employers that all that moving around was due to a family emergency, etc., however if you intend to keep doing it, expect your potential prospects to dry up.

Answer (score 1):

> Is moving often going to look like job-hopping?

To a point, yes it will hurt you, but its not a death sentence as implied by others.

> With the above in mind, will we look like job-hoppers to interviewers
>   when the reason for leaving a job has nothing to do with the job at
>   all, and rather where and how we choose to live?

I would urge you to explain this pattern of moving straight away in your cover letter.  This way the employer knows what they are getting into before you are called in for an interview.  There are **some** potential employers that will view you as a job hopper, and you really cannot do anything about that.

If you happen to be a good software engineer changing jobs *every two to three years*, at least in my region, isn't that unusual due to the supply/demand factor.

> Is there any structural way we could protect ourselves from these
>   perceptions?

Besides an upfront explanation in your **cover letter**, there isn't much more you can do.  There is more to a candidate than how long they have been on a given job.   I do suspect at some point though your options will become more and more limited / harder to find and you will need to settle in for longer periods of time as your career progresses.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The OP did not elaborate as to exactly why they are moving so often, so any response beyond my answer is just speculation.  The OP as you said in your comment will have to get efficient at telling that story, but its not the gloomy death sentence implied by others either.